# ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS grub error

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, boot, grub

I downloaded the .iso file for ubuntu desktop 12.04.3 from the official download page of ubuntu. I am using a 64bit system with the following specs:

-Intel i7 3610QM
 - 1TB HDD
 - 8gb ram
 - asus k55vm

Windows 7 os is already present and i am trying to install ubuntu in another partition. The installation goes well untill the very end, when grub2 is being installed and shows the error message-
 "the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader the system will not load"

I tried different solutions that i found on the internet. But not much luck in multibooting ubuntu and windows7 so far.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable BIOS QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT).

Then install Ubuntu 12.10 <- IMPORTANT 12.10

Then try to install, if needed, grub-efi-amd64-signed

Comment: But i needed the LTS.

Comment: is the 12.10 as stable?
could u provide the terminal commands or links for the terminal commands of the above?